# Impedance triangle

Tags: impedance

Impedance triangle of RL circuit with R having phase angle of 0 degrees and XL having phase angle of 90 degrees looks like Right angle triangle, if we take R as reference vector

How it looks like if R has phase angle of 20 degrees and XL has phase angle of 90 degrees and taking XL as reference vector?

Comment: What do you think? what did you try?

Comment: I refered books and searched online and came to know that R always have phase angle of 0 degrees because there will be no leading and lagging between voltage and current. But still i am curious that how phasor triangle looks if R has phase angle of some value other than Zero. If it is not R and XL and consider them as A and B, how the triangle looks if vector B has phase angle of 90 degrees and is taken as reference and A has phase angle of 20 degrees.

Comment: Your analysis is right. I feel that the question is not formed correctly. It is written in confusing way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a series circuit of R and L, the angle of \$\omega L\$ is always 90 degrees relative to the angle for resistance. If you choose resistance to be your reference then R will be horizontal (the standard for any phasor reference) and \$\omega L\$ will be vertical.

You could actually take anything as your reference but \$\omega L\$ will always be 90 degrees to R. You could take \$\omega L\$ as your reference and it will be horizontal; then R would be rotated around from the horizontal to -90 degrees. Always \$\omega L\$ and R for a series circuit will have a 90 degrees phase angle difference.

> How it looks like if R has phase angle of 20 degrees and XL has phase
>   angle of 90 degrees and taking XL as reference vector?

That is impossible. If R is at 20 degrees then \$\omega L\$ will be at 110 degrees.

Comment: Why it is impossible? I am not asking in terms of impedance. I am asking whether is it possible or not in normal mathematics.

Comment: It is impossible because, for an inductor, V = L di/dt and if the common current flowing through both components is mathematically integrated to find inductor voltage, for a sinewave current (a la phasor diagrams), inductor voltage will be a negative cosine signal i.e. -90 degrees to the current. Voltage across the resistor will be in phase with current hence the two impedances **ARE ALWAYS** 90 degrees apart.

Comment: @chiduruppula yea in maths you can draw vectors like that. Take -ve angles clock wise and +ve angles anticlockwise from the origin of reference vector.